# Density funciton for minimum of $n$ independent variables

Tags: probability, derivatives

I am not a mathematics guy, and the question which I am gonna ask would be pretty simple for mathematicians. In fact I am doing research and was reading some blogs. I wanted to derive the density function for $n$ number of independent variables. following relation I find on Internet for calculating CDF of $n$ number of independent variables
$$
F(T) = 1 – (1 - F_1(T)) (1 - F_2(T)) \dots (1- F_n(T)) = 1 – \prod_{i=1}^n F_i (T)
$$
 but for PDF they says that take the derivative of it . In fact I learned mathematics decades ago, so I don't know how to do that. Can some one just help me in steps how to take derivate of above equation and finally what would be the Density function?

Comment: What is CDF and PDF? Is this from Economics?

Comment: CDF - Cumulative Distribution Function, PDF - Probability Density Function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the n variables are independent you have that $F_{X_1,X_2\cdots X_n}(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=\mathbb{P}\{X_1\leq x_1, X_2\leq x_2\cdots ,X_n\leq x_n\}=\mathbb{P}\{X_1\leq x_1\}\cdots \mathbb{P}\{X_n\leq x_n\}=F_{X_1}(x_1)\cdot F_{X_2}(x_2)\cdots F_{X_n}(x_n)$. 
Now, by the definition of density and cumulative distribution you have that
$F_{X_1,X_2\cdots X_n}(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}\int_{-\infty}^{x_2}\cdots \int_{-\infty}^{x_n} f_{X_1,X_2\cdots X_n}(t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_n)dt_1dt_2\cdots dt_n$. On the other hand
$F_{X_1}(x_1)\cdot F_{X_2}(x_2)\cdots F_{X_n}(x_n)=\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}f_{X_1}(t_1)dt_1\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{x_2}f_{X_2}(t_2)dt_2\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{x_n}f_{X_n}(t_n)dt_n=\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}\int_{-\infty}^{x_2}\cdots \int_{-\infty}^{x_n} f_{X_1}(t_1)f_{X_2}(t_2)\cdots f_{X_n}(t_n)dt_1dt_2\cdots dt_n.$ Because the left hand sides we showed earlier are equal, it follows that the joint density function of independent RVs is the product of the individual density functions. Hence, no need to differentiate the cdf. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. well, i found this relation if we go for derivation ... F(T)=∏(j=1)^n f_j(T)  ∏(i=1)^n〖F_i (T)〗 such that j!=i (not equal to), I want to know is this relation and the one you have described are conceptually equal??

secondly it would be of great help if you can elaborate , how does taking derivative gives us this result?

Comment: it would help if you shared the internet source

Answer (score 1):

Take logarithm and then take derivatives.

Comment: can you be more clear.

Comment: If you want the derivative of the product, take log. that will convert everything to a sum of log terms. Take derivative of each term.
$g(x) = \prod_if_i(x)$ then $\log g(x) = \sum_i \log f_i(x)$. Now taking derivatives, 

$$
\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} = \sum_i f_i'(x)/f_i(x) 
$$
which gives $g'(x) = \prod f_i(x)(\sum_i f_i'(x)/f_i(x) )$ which when simplified gives the answer.